# Is there a way to say "the opposite of a statement is not true"?

Tags: vocabulary

"the opposite of a statement is also true" can be said as "vice versa".

Is there a way to say "the opposite of a statement is *not* true"?

Comment: Unidirectional or non-conversely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A affects B, but not the other way around.

A affects B, but not the converse.

A affects B, but not reciprocally.

Answer (score 9):

When the opposite is true:

> Jasper likes Lauren, and vice versa.

When the opposite is false:

> Jasper likes Lauren, but not vice versa.

This simple negation works well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Latin expert but how about "vice non versa"

Comment: If that's not a phrase, it should be!

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain why this would be a good choice.